# Averaging Numbers with Embedded Python Code inside HTML

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, jinja2

This won't be a long or complex question. I'm just wondering if there is any simple way to accomplish calculating an average of numbers pulled from the datastore.

At the moment, I have this for loop inside my HTML:

```
{% for rating_tmp in ratings %}

  {{rating_tmp.rating}}

{% endfor %}
```

... and it works nicely. Every time I add a value, the for loop places it on the page in a row:

2.5 4.5 2.5 3.5 etc...

Averaging numbers is obviously the sum of the numbers over the number of values. Can I throw more python in there and accomplish this all within the HTML? Or is this something that should go into main.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do this in a Jinja template, but I wouldn't recommend it. What you're doing here is pretty clearly logic, not layout, so you should do it in code, and pass it in as a variable or a property. If you change how you average in future, for instance, you should be changing the code that generates it, not the template that displays it.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely! Just calculate the average in python inside HTML file. There is nothing wrong with doing that.

Comment: Does jinja2 actually allow arbitrary python code these days? :/

Comment: @Wooble - no, it doesn't.  It does however allow you to do simple arithmetic and set variables ... which is all that is being done in this case.